# ToolTip not visible on LineChart on React Native application

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-svg, react-native-svg-charts

**Background:**

Currently trying to implement a line chart with tooltip using react-svg-chart library by following this [Tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/adding-tooltip-to-react-native-charts-67606c5d3182).

**Problem:**

The onClick decorator shows up on my phone on the Expo app([This code](https://snack.expo.io/@vijayr0753/chart-draft)) and works perfectly, but when I put the exact same code in my application the tooltip does not show up. If I print out a console.log for the dots - I am getting the response, however the view with the y value does not show up.
Any idea why?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code you've shared in the snack. The problem is likely due to a part of your code you're not showing.

Comment: Hey thank you, but I actually figured out the problem for this. I just had to update my libraries, but thank you. If you dont mind could you take a look at this - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63864016/positioning-icon-in-svg-in-react-native?noredirect=1#comment113098527_63864016)